# How to access req.session variables from within socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, session-cookies

I am working with express and socket.io. I have some `req.session` variables I wish to access from within socket.io. I read this post on [socket.io and session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641053/socket-io-and-session) and I am still very confused as to how I can get a `req.session` variable.

Comment: Note that the answer you've mentioned is for an older version of socket.io.  Perhaps take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397574/how-to-access-session-in-express-outside-of-the-req?rq=1) instead.  Can't say if it still applies personally, as I don't use socket.io.  You can also read about authorization on the [socket.io wiki](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by using your session store from inside your socket - which will have your all you session variables. This is how I do an authorization (compare cookie ID with session ID from database).

```
io.set('authorization', function (data, accept) {

    if (data.headers.cookie) {

        data.cookie = utils.parseCookie(data.headers.cookie);
        data.sessionID = data.cookie['connect.sid'].split('.')[0].substring(2);

        sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session) {
                // now you have all session variables
        });                     
    }
});
```